# Model "half an inverted U-shape" in a regression

Tags: regression, linear

How do I best model the "right half an inverted U-shaped" relationship in a linear regression?

Including the squared term works (to model a full U-shape), but the extremum is at a very negative value, far outside the range of values observed (or even observable) for the independent variable, so it feels like there should be a more efficient way to model this. Is there?

The following picture may illustrate what I am after:
[image: Picture]

The dependent variable is simply not defined for the left part of the scale...

Comment: 1. It's difficult to picture both the nature and the extent of what you're describing. Are you able to show some plots of what you're talking about?  2. What's the response variable?

Comment: If you are never intending to extrapolate below zero does it matter what happens there?

Comment: no, I guess it does not -- just wondering if including a squared term is the right way to model this relationship then...

Comment: Thanks. Your x-variable is clearly ordered categories. What's the y-axis?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, the image was just an example. Actually both my independent and my dependent variable would be continuous!